# Floating aside in IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css-float, internet-explorer-7

I've just made a Wordpress page with a simple HTML 5 structure.

```
<section>
    <article>Content</article>
    <aside>Form</aside>
</section>
```

Inside the article I have made different subsections with images and a data list. 
It works nicely everywhere except for IE 7-8 where the aside goes down in the page and it seems it can't be floated in any way.
NOTICE: I've used html5-shiv script to make html5 tags recognizable by IE.

Here is my CSS for the content and aside part:

```
article {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
}

aside {
    float:left;
    width:350px; 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I would like to underline that the part I've coded works correctly in other pages like:

http://www.dottcar.it/auto-noleggio-lungo-termine_vantaggi/

but it seems broken in the offer page:

http://www.dottcar.it/mini-countryman-one-d/

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Ehehe, you could be right but I've used html5-shiv script to make it recognizible. Sorry for the forgetfullness ;)

Comment: Just done it, thanks